# Remove Backslash from html string in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have the below method to convert a docx to html.

```
public String extractText(String file) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException, OpenXML4JException, XmlException {
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(bibliothequePath + file + DOCX))) {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);
        XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create().URIResolver(new FileURIResolver(new File("word/media")));
        File imageFolder = new File(bibliothequePath + "/images/" + in);
        options.setExtractor( new FileImageExtractor( imageFolder ) );
        options.URIResolver( new FileURIResolver( imageFolder ) );
        XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

I get the output like below, the problem is that i get backslash `\` in the start and the end of each style, class, src...

```
<div style=\"width:595.0pt;margin-bottom:56.0pt;margin-top:45.0pt;margin-left:45.0pt;margin-right:62.0pt;\"><p class=\"Normal En-tte\"><img src=\"C:\\documents\\bibliotheque\\images\\java.io.FileInputStream@2ec458bf/word/media/image1.jpeg\" width=\"107.65pt\" height=\"47.05pt\"/></p>
```

I tired with `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4` and i tried also to replace `\"` with `"` by `out.toString().replace("\\\"", "\"")`, but it's not working, it always shows me the same output.

Comment: Do you really mean to have the toString() of the FileInputStream in the output as well?  images\\java.io.FileInputStream@2ec458bf/word...  I suspect you wanted the filename or something like that.

Comment: Please try `out.toString().replace("\\", "")`